# how to raise a timeout exception after X seconds in python

Tags: python, exception, timeout

I have a function and I need to raise exception after X seconds how can I do this?
I try this code but It doesen't work:

```
from eventlet.timeout import Timeout
timeout = Timeout(seconds, exception)
try:
   do somethins
finally:
   timeout.cancel()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the timeout documentation](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/timeout.html):

> There are two Timeout caveats to be aware of:
>
> - If the code block in the try/finally or with-block never cooperatively yields, the timeout cannot be raised. In Eventlet, this
>     should rarely be a problem, but be aware that you cannot time out
>     CPU-only operations with this class.
> - If the code block catches and doesn't re-raise BaseException (for example, with except:), then it will catch the Timeout exception, and
>     might not abort as intended.

If you are doing expensive calculation without doing any IO/[sleep](http://eventlet.net/doc/basic_usage.html#eventlet.sleep) in a loop, timeout will not occur.

Comment: I have telnet connection and I need to raise exception after X second if the connection dosen't do anything